# Android video rendering to glsurfaceview in GB(API 10) glReadPixels

Tags: android, video, glsurfaceview

I want to use `glSurfaceView` to render video in GB(`API 10`), so that i can use `glReadPixels` call to get the frame data. But `setSurface` in MediaPlayer requires `API 14`. Now any way can i get my work done, any Support libraries, or native code?

Ultimately i want to capture frames of video to JPEG images while the video is rendered in fullscreen. The cartoon video is in BGRA format(hope so!)

Comment: FWIW, API 8 was Froyo. Most Gingerbread devices will have at least 2.3.3, which is API 10.  Unfortunately the video and graphics APIs were rather limited back then (3 years ago yesterday for 2.3.3).  You may need to use a software video decoder like ffmpeg.

Comment: Is openmax il possible in API 10, because i see stagefright related libraries in /system/libs/ ?